# Find all Duplicates from a Table In Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which contains two columns of Urls and it contains duplicates.I'm looping through each row but have no idea to check duplicates.I want to send oldurl as parameter to check duplicates and get them.I don't want count but the list of all the duplicates.Can anyone help me

```
OldUrl     NewUrl    
---------------------
Google     Google.in
Amazon     Amazon.in
```

Comment: mysql != sql-server - pick one tag

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT oldurl
FROM mytable
GROUP BY oldurl
HAVING COUNT(*) >1
```

or if you need to see all duplicated records:

```
SELECT mytable.*, t.counter
FROM mytable
INNER JOIN(
SELECT oldurl, COUNT(*) as counter
FROM mytable
GROUP BY oldurl
HAVING COUNT(*) >1) t
ON t.oldurl=mytable.oldurl
```